# Overlapping booking system html table representation

Tags: algorithm

Lets say we have a car rental company and that we have multiple cars of the same type. When a user books a car he doesn’t book a specific car but one of its type.

Which algorithm is the best to display/arrange/sort the bookings on a timeline table, looking like this:

```
/*
 *       | 09 - 10 - 11 - 12 - 13 - 14 - 15 - 16 - 17 |
 *       |      A    A    A    A    A                 |
 *       |      D    D    D    B    B    B            |
 *       |      D    D    D    B    B    B            |
 *       |           C    C    C    C                 |
 *       |           C    C    C    C                 |
 *       |           C    C    C    C                 |
 * */
```

Where each line represents a car of the same type, and each letter represents 1 booking (1 user can book multiple cars). The system has built in detection so, you cannot book a car if there are no cars left (like from 11. to 14. there are no cars available).

There are multiple ways to sort the bookings, but an algorithm (or some pointers on how to) that always returns the same order and works for all (or close) different cases would be great.

Comment: What is the specific issue you're having trouble with?

Comment: Like I wrote in the last paragraph, there are multiple ways to sort the bookings, and the current algorithm is not really efficient and it doesn't order them in the same way every time. I would like some help/pointers on which algorithm would be the best to tackle this problem.